Why the method _castToPure in hardhat/console.sol can convert a view method to a pure one?
I have a question when read the console.sol. There is a method named _castToPure that can convert a view method _sendLogPayloadImplementation into a pure method. I cant understand the reason and principle for it? Where can I learn about it?
    function _castToPure(
      function(bytes memory) internal view fnIn
    ) internal pure returns (function(bytes memory) pure fnOut) {
        assembly {
            fnOut := fnIn
        }
    }

    function _sendLogPayloadImplementation(bytes memory payload) internal view {
        address consoleAddress = CONSOLE_ADDRESS;
        /// @solidity memory-safe-assembly
        assembly {
            pop(
                staticcall(
                    gas(),
                    consoleAddress,
                    add(payload, 32),
                    mload(payload),
                    0,
                    0
                )
            )
        }
    }


This function is called to avoid having solc throwing when trying to cast a view function into a pure one (doing it in assembly bypass the compiler check)
Without the assembly block (ie just assigning fnIn to fnOut), this fails to compile TypeError: Type function (bytes memory) view is not implicitly convertible to expected type function (bytes memory) pure. and you cannot use an intermediary base-type, like you would do to cast an address into an uint256 for instance (uint256(uint160(address(0))))

Many thanks for your replying！Can we cast a view into pure in every case? A view method will read the storage of the contract, so how can it be executed correctly if it be casted into pure？
